# Can't access my match.props in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm gonna post some code, because it appears I have not included something.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {updateSearch, getSearchResults} from '../actions/qb-actions';
import {valueAccepted} from '../actions/tree-actions';
import {addNewElement} from '../services/commonComponents';
import QueryBuilder from './QueryBuilder';
import SearchResults from './SearchResults';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {checkIncludeColumns} from '../services/commonComponents';
import {removeSpaces} from '../services/values';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

class SearchBooksAdvanced extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        const { match: { params } } = this.props;
//I want to use match.params here, but it is coming back undefined. 
    }

    qb=()=>{
    }

    postResults = () => {
        this.qb();
    }

    render() {
        return (<div >
            <QueryBuilder postResults={this.postResults}/>
            <SearchResults 
                qb={qb => {this.qb = qb}}
                tree={this.props.tree.tree}
            />
        </div>);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
     return{
        options: state.options,
        tree: state.tree,
        goToSearch: state.goToSearch
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateSearch, getSearchResults})(SearchBooksAdvanced);
```

A little abbreviated class. Here is where I am calling my routings:

```
<main>
    <Switch>
        <AuthenticatedRoute login={this.props.login} path={`${this.props.match.path}`} exact component={Landing} isLoggedOut={this.props.login.ckUser.isLoggedOut}/>
        <AuthenticatedRoute login={this.props.login} path={`${this.props.match.path}/search/:searchID`} exact component={SearchBooksAdvanced}  isLoggedOut={this.props.login.ckUser.isLoggedOut}/>
        <AuthenticatedRoute login={this.props.login} path={`${this.props.match.path}/book/:bookID`} exact component={BookDetail}  isLoggedOut={this.props.login.ckUser.isLoggedOut}/>
        <AuthenticatedRoute login={this.props.login} path={`${this.props.match.path}/routing/:routingID/:versionID`} exact component={RoutingDetail}  isLoggedOut={this.props.login.ckUser.isLoggedOut}/>
        <Redirect to={`${this.props.match.url}`} />
    </Switch>
</main>
```

My AuthenicatedRoute class is as follows:

```
import React               from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props =>
        (

            !props.isLoggedOut && localStorage.getItem('user') ?

            <Component {...props}/>
         :
            <span><Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/bis/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }}/><span>redirected</span></span>

    )}/>
);

export default AuthenticatedRoute
```

What is weird here, is my props.match.params.someID worked for my other two classes, but when I called it for SeachBooksAdvanced class it fails to find it. Please let me know if you see an inconsistency in my code. TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC on route components that you use `connect` on.

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { updateSearch, getSearchResults }
  )(SearchBooksAdvanced)
);
```